# this site is supported by jsecoin message

Tags: magento

i am getting this message on my magento website.
I have deleted all the website and restored it from the old backup, but still this message is coming. What will be the possible causes of this?

Comment: did you at anypoint in time include jsecoin? if not, you might have been hacked and someone injected the code

Comment: i deleted the whole website and re-upload a old backup but it still the same, looks like any extension or plugin causing this

Comment: have you checken the installed modules?